# R: function that returns a result for each row of a data.frame

Tags: r, function, loops, while-loop, dataframe

Hello i am a beginner in R and i'm trying to write a function for a sensitivity analysis that from a sample "X" (a data table with 12 columns and 2500 observation each) returns a vector of 2500 values called Global Cost (one for each row). It does work properly but the problem is that **j1, j2, and j3** that should be re-calculated for each row(for while loops) **are fixed with the first "row"** of variables so **only the first** result is actually correct.

```
lcc<-function(X){
#initial costs
globalcost<-(X[,3]+X[,4]+X[,5]);       
#replacement costs 1
j1<-X[,6];
while(j1<30){globalcost<-globalcost+((X[,3]*((1/(1+((X[,2]-X[,1])/(1+X[,1]))))^j1)));j1<-j1+j1};        
#replacement costs 2
j2<-X[,7];
while(j2<=30){globalcost<-globalcost+((X[,4]*((1/(1+((X[,2]-X[,1])/(1+X[,1]))))^j2)));j2<-j2+j2};       
#replacement costs 3
j3<-X[,8];
while(j3<=30){globalcost<-globalcost+((X[,5]*((1/(1+((X[,2]-X[,1])/(1+X[,1]))))^j3)));j3<-j3+j3};       
#energy costs
globalcost<-globalcost+((5375.81*0.0507*X[,12])*((1-(1+((X[,2]-X[,1])/(1+X[,1])))^-30)/((X[,2]-X[,1])/(1+X[,1]))));        
#maintenance costs 1
globalcost<-globalcost+(X[,9]*((1-(1+((X[,2]-X[,1])/(1+X[,1])))^-30)/((X[,2]-X[,1])/(1+X[,1]))));         
#maintenance costs 1
globalcost<-globalcost+(X[,10]*((1-(1+((X[,2]-X[,1])/(1+X[,1])))^-30)/((X[,2]-X[,1])/(1+X[,1]))));        
#maintenance costs 3
globalcost<-globalcost+(X[,11]*((1-(1+((X[,2]-X[,1])/(1+X[,1])))^-30)/((X[,2]-X[,1])/(1+X[,1]))));     
#result
return(globalcost)}
```

I tried to create a 'for loop' like this

```
lcc<-function(X){
for (i in 1:2500){
    #initial costs
    globalcost<-(X[i,3]+X[i,4]+X[i,5]);
    #replacement costs 1
    j1<-X[i,6];
    while(j1<30){globalcost<-globalcost+((X[i,3]*((1/(1+((X[i,2]-X[i,1])/(1+X[i,1]))))^j1)));j1<-j1+j1};
    #replacement costs 2
    j2<-X[i,7];
    while(j2<=30){globalcost<-globalcost+((X[i,4]*((1/(1+((X[i,2]-X[i,1])/(1+X[i,1]))))^j2)));j2<-j2+j2};
    #replacement costs 3
    j3<-X[i,8];
    while(j3<=30){globalcost<-globalcost+((X[i,5]*((1/(1+((X[i,2]-X[i,1])/(1+X[i,1]))))^j3)));j3<-j3+j3};
    #energy costs
    globalcost<-globalcost+((5375.81*0.0507*X[i,12])*((1-(1+((X[i,2]-X[i,1])/(1+X[i,1])))^-30)/((X[i,2]-X[i,1])/(1+X[i,1]))));
    #maintenance costs 1
    globalcost<-globalcost+(X[i,9]*((1-(1+((X[i,2]-X[i,1])/(1+X[i,1])))^-30)/((X[i,2]-X[i,1])/(1+X[i,1]))));
    #maintenance costs 1
    globalcost<-globalcost+(X[i,10]*((1-(1+((X[i,2]-X[i,1])/(1+X[i,1])))^-30)/((X[i,2]-X[i,1])/(1+X[i,1]))));
    #maintenance costs 3
    globalcost<-globalcost+(X[i,11]*((1-(1+((X[i,2]-X[i,1])/(1+X[i,1])))^-30)/((X[i,2]-X[i,1])/(1+X[i,1]))));}
    #risultato
return(globalcost)}
```

but in this case the function returns "globalcost" **only for the last line**!

Then i have to put this function in sobol `x <- sobol(model = lcc, X1 = X1, X2 = X2, order = 2, nboot = 100)` to obtain the sensitivity analysis

Thank you..!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with `while(j1<30)`? You only want to apply the condition to `j1` where the values are below `30`? Because that's not what you are achieving here.

Comment: It's a calculation for replacement that should be done if a number ( `j1=X[,6]` ) is less than 30 and repeat like this: CALC^ **j1** + CALC^ **j1+j1** + CALC^ **j1+j1+j1** and break if j1>30

Comment: Ah yes, I was reading the first script where it doesn't achieve that (since you are supplying a whole vector), but it should work for the 2nd script.

Answer (score 0):

I partially solved the problem adding

- `gc<-c()`before the "for loop"
- `gc[i]<-c(globalcost)`inside the loop
- `return(gc)` after the "for loop"

But now when i put my function as a model in the sensitivity analysis: `x <- sobol(model = lcc, X1 = X1, X2 = X2, order = 2, nboot = 100)` I get this error:

```
Error in colSums(d[, -1] * d[, 1]) : 
  'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions
```

Comment: Solved entering `nrow(X)` in `for (i in 1:nrow(X))`